# (JS) why 2 date type variables share the same content?

Tags: javascript

Can you help me to understand why d1 has different value in each alert() ?
Thanks.

```
<script>
d1 = new Date("01/01/2015");
d2 = d1;
alert(d1);
d2.setDate(d2.getDate()+10);
alert(d1);
</script>
```

Comment: BTW, using the Date constructor to parse date strings is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Because objects are reference types, and in the line `d2 = d1` a pointer is passed to d2 that points to d1 and if you `d2.setDate(d2.getDate()+10);` execute this line is same as you edited `d1.setDate(d1.getDate()+10);`

Comment: Well, the value of the variable *d1* is a reference and `d2 = d1` copies the reference and assigns it to *d2* so that both variables reference the same Date object.

Comment: Thank you. So, as Date is an object and just copy the pointer. So, I need to create a new object and copy it like this <script> d1 = new Date("01/01/2015"); d2 = new Date(); d2.setDate(d1.getDate()); </script>